# Get Facebook access token in Json

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, playframework

I am using this API call to get Facebook long lived token.

```
ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        F.Promise<WSResponse> response = WS.url("https://graph.facebook.com/oaut.....")
                .get();
```

I managed to extract the access token using this line of code.

`wsResponse.getBody();`

but i need to get that in jSON format.
any idea???

Answer (score 1):

The WSResponse class has a method "asJson()"

so instead of :

```
wsResponse.getBody();
```

do

```
wsResponse.asJson();
```

Comment: i tried wsResponse.asJson(); but it gives parsing exception!!

Comment: what's the parse exception?